# Show the data of JSON response using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I am using an API, which returns a JSON whenever you search something. It is basically a auto complete search API. Whenever you start typing in the box, it hits the API endpoint with a GET request and returns a JSON. Suppose, you start typing "`lucky`" , then request is `https://autocomplete.clearbit.com/v1/companies/suggest?query=lucky` and JSON response is

```
[{"name":"Lucky Brand","domain":"luckybrand.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/luckybrand.com"},{"name":"LuckyVitamin.com","domain":"luckyvitamin.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/luckyvitamin.com"},{"name":"Lucky Gunner Ammo","domain":"luckygunner.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/luckygunner.com"},{"name":"Lucky Orange","domain":"luckyorange.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/luckyorange.com"},{"name":"Lucky's Market","domain":"luckysmarket.com","logo":"https://logo.clearbit.com/luckysmarket.com"}]
```

It returns name, domain and logo. I have a html search box so, whenever you start typing, I want to show the `logo image`, `name` and `domain` in a row of each item. But it is not properly showing. This is my code,

html :-

```
<input type="text" placeholder="type something ..." id="suggest" />
```

css :-

```
body{
    padding: 30px;
}
```

JS :- (I am using jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#suggest").autocomplete({
        delay: 100,
        source: function (request, response) {

            // Suggest URL
            var suggestURL = "https://autocomplete.clearbit.com/v1/companies/suggest?query=%QUERY";
            suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

            // JSON Request
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                jsonCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                url: suggestURL
            })
            .success(function(data){
                response(data[]); //Here I want to pass all the return 
                                  //items. I can show only one item, 
                                  //like data[1].name but not sure how 
                                  //to go through each item.

            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: `But is not showing properly` - Define properly?

Comment: a lot of ways to do it, looping or use some ES6 like map

Comment: I'm slightly confused in that if the endpoint returns json, why you are trying to use a jsonpCallback.  It would also be helpful if you noted if you put a console log in the success handler for any value if you saw it in the console, and indeed if you see any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the forEach() Method to go through your Response e.g.

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.name, item.logo, item.domain);
});
```

more about forEach [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)